# How to make your SharePoint Online /Office 365 site a public facing website?

Tags: sharepoint-online

Is there any way to make your SharePoint Online /Office 365 site a public facing website? All I have been trying here is to create a content to shared publicly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you may have known, MS has [deprecated public site feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/sites/public-websites-be-discontinued) in SharePoint Online since 2015. We cannot create a public site now.

If you want to share contents like documents to public, we can [create anonymous access for sharing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/solutions/collaborate-on-documents?view=o365-worldwide). Actual process in short for end users [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/share-sharepoint-files-or-folders-1fe37332-0f9a-4719-970e-d2578da4941c?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us).

For sharing site to public, for now the only way will be add the public users as guests first. Then they will be able to access contents in the site with the permission you grant.

All these are concluded in External Sharing feature in SharePoint Online/M365, you can get more detailed information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/external-sharing-overview).